# VB .NET HTMLAgilityPack Colon Separated Values

Tags: vb.net, parsing, html-agility-pack

Is there a way to get the values within a tag using HTMLAgilityPack?
My variable `dataNode` is an `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode` and contains:

```
Dim doc as New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

doc.LoadHtml("
<div id="container" data="id:12,country:usa,city:oregon,id:13,country:usa,city:atlanta">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
")
```

Would like to get the value of each `id`, `country`,`city`. They repeat within the tag and have different values.

```
Dim dataNode as HtmlAgililtyPack.HtmlNode

dataNode = doc.documentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div")
txtbox.text = dataNode.Attributes("id[1]").value
```

This gives an error `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Hello :D Im currently testing your code have a look at this one hehe https://dotnetfiddle.net/DI3N6p

Comment: If Im done I will post the answer

Comment: Can you please edit your post? What is your target output?

Comment: my bad i already see what output you want

Comment: i can get the word google because it is inside the div how ever the others are not

Comment: Is it really necessary to use HTMLAgilitPack?

Comment: You need the `"data"` attribute, not the `"id"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `"data"` attribute, not the `"id"` attribute.

Once you have the value of the correct attribute, you will need to parse it into some data structure suitable for holding each part of the data, for example:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Public Class LocationDatum
        Property ID As Integer
        Property Country As String
        Property City As String

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return $"ID={ID}, Country={Country}, City={City}"
        End Function

    End Class


    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

        doc.LoadHtml("
<div id=""container"" data=""id:12,country:usa,city:oregon,id:13,country:usa,city:atlanta"">
    <a href=""http://www.google.com"">Google</a>
</div>
")

        Dim dataNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div")
        Dim rawData = dataNode.Attributes("data").Value
        Dim dataParts = rawData.Split(","c)

        Dim locationData As New List(Of LocationDatum)

        ' A simple way of parsing the data
        For i = 0 To dataParts.Count - 1 Step 3
            If i + 2 < dataParts.Count Then
                Dim id As Integer = -1
                Dim country As String = ""
                Dim city As String = ""
                ' used to check all three required parts have been found:
                Dim partsFoundFlags = 0
                For j = 0 To 2
                    Dim itemParts = dataParts(i + j).Split(":"c)
                    Select Case itemParts(0)
                        Case "id"
                            id = CInt(itemParts(1))
                            partsFoundFlags = partsFoundFlags Or 1
                        Case "country"
                            country = itemParts(1)
                            partsFoundFlags = partsFoundFlags Or 2
                        Case "city"
                            city = itemParts(1)
                            partsFoundFlags = partsFoundFlags Or 4
                    End Select
                Next
                If partsFoundFlags = 7 Then
                    locationData.Add(New LocationDatum With {.ID = id, .Country = country, .City = city})
                End If
            End If

        Next

        For Each d In locationData
            Console.WriteLine(d)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Which outputs:

> ID=12, Country=usa, City=oregon
>   ID=13, Country=usa, City=atlanta

It is resistant to *some* data malformations, such as id/city/country being in a different order, and spurious data at the end.

You would, of course, put the parsing code into its own function.